# intellij idea can not open at Ubuntu18.04

Tags: intellij-idea

I download idea Community version, but can not opened.

it is blocked by the page:
JetBrains Privacy Policy

[image]

and the command line output those messages:

```
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Option UseConcMarkSweepGC was deprecated in version 9.0 and will likely be removed in a future release.
9月 22, 2020 6:19:21 下午 java.util.prefs.FileSystemPreferences$6 runWARNING: Prefs file removed in background /home/mi/.java/.userPrefs/prefs.xml
```

but I can open it by `sudo ./idea.sh`.

Comment: Do you have sogou pinyin input installed?

Comment: yes, of course, I have installed it.

Comment: Please try to temporarily uninstall it. It should help. Also you may use baidu pinyin(https://srf.baidu.com/site/guanwang_linux/index.html) instead of it.

Comment: Amazing, it's works, why?

Comment: Looks like some issue with input popup.

Answer (score 0):

For me, when I uninstall the sougoupinyin, it's works.

If you have installed sougoupinyin, you can uninstall it first.